# SignalR - Having the client and server on different domains while using the auto-generated hub

Tags: angularjs, json, html, requirejs, signalr

Is it possible to run the client and it's auto-generated hub on a different server/domain than the SignalR .NET backend hub, ie. the one that is pushing data towards the client?

Client domain: **lgi15q1026**

Server domain: **lgi14q1030**

I was wondering if this is correct. To auto-generate the client hub, we have to insert a script line in the html view like this:

```
<script src="signalr/hubs" />
```

But this obviously won't work because the client hub is on a different machine than the server hub. This will generate this URL:

> http://lgi15q1026/Board.WebApp/signalr/hubs?_=1452624922877

Which results in a 404 error. So to fix this, I would have to do this:

```
<script src="//lgi14q1030/Board.WebApp/signalr/hubs" />
```

Will this work?

EDIT: I am using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) as a dependency manager over AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `jquery.signalR.js` script was loaded using RequireJS, you cannot auto-generate the client hub script by doing: `<script src="signalr/hubs" />`

Solution is to remove the `<script>` tag from the html and load the script using RequireJS:

**require.config.json :**

```
{
    "baseUrl": "",
    "paths": {
        "signalR": "bower_components/signalr/jquery.signalR",
        "signalRhub": "http://lgi14q1030:80/Board.WebApp/signalr/hubs?noext"
},
 "shim": {
     "signalR": {
            "deps": [ "jquery" ],
            "exports": "$.connection"
        },
        "signalRhub": {
            "deps": [ "signalR" ]
        }
}
```

Of course you have to inject the javascript into your controller:

**angularJS controller:**

```
define(
    ['../app', '../services/eventDataService', 'signalRhub'],
    function (eventsApp) {
        'use strict';

        eventsApp.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$filter',
            function ($scope, $filter) {

                var hubUrl = "http://lgi14q1030/Board.WebApp/signalr";
                $.connection.hub.url = hubUrl;
                var myHub= $.connection.myHub;
```